# Obj C bridging header does not seem to matter?

Tags: swift, frameworks, bridging-header

I have a Swift / Parse iPhone project in Xcode. I have added Parse frameworks and as long as I `import Bolts` and `import Parse` in my swift file I am able to use all parse functions. I am now wondering, why do I need the Obj C bridging header at all? Currently there is nothing in it, yet everywhere it says that you need to properly setup your bridging header for Parse to work in Swift projects?

Comment: It depends entirely on how your project is set up.  The bridging header is only necessary when you have Objective-C & Swift code *in the same project* that needs to see each other.  If these things are in other projects, it works differently.

Comment: @nhgrif: Well the whole parse framework is in Obj-C, so technically bridging header is required, then how is it working without?

Comment: Is it in the same target?

Comment: yes, I only have one target and all swift files and frameworks are in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is in your deployment target. For iOS8, you can use embedded frameworks, so you can import frameworks just with a simple
`import FrameworkName`. If you use CocoaPods, you can add `use_frameworks!` directive to your `podfile` and you can then use all pods as Frameworks without a bridging header.

If you want to provide a support for iOS7, you have to still use a bridging header, because embedded frameworks are not supported with this version of iOS.